# Joomla: K2 - How to strip out curly brackets from meta description using preg_replace

Tags: php, joomla, metadata, curly-brackets, k2

I need to strip out some curly brackets from the meta description which is created by `joomla/K2`.

I found two `php` solutions to strip unneeded curly brackets:

```
$description = preg_replace( '/{.+?}/', '', $description);
```

and

```
$metaDescItem = str_replace('/{.+?}/', '', $metaDescItem);
```

There are different curly brackets which control the content of my app:

`{123456789}, {123456789,123456789}, {URL}, {}`

The best solution would be to get rid of any curly bracket in the meta description output.

I am new to php and I am not sure which function is right.

Next problem is, that I don't know where to insert the function in the `php` file of K2.

I think I found the right `php` file which generates the meta description.

Here is the quote from `/components/com_k2/views/item/view.html.php`:

```
// Set metadata
    if ($item->metadesc)
    {
        $document->setDescription((K2_JVERSION == '15') ? htmlspecialchars($item->metadesc, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') : $item->metadesc);
    }
    else
    {
        $metaDescItem = preg_replace("#{(.*?)}(.*?){/(.*?)}#s", '', $item->introtext.' '.$item->fulltext);
        $metaDescItem = strip_tags($metaDescItem);
        $metaDescItem = K2HelperUtilities::characterLimit($metaDescItem, $params->get('metaDescLimit', 150));
        $document->setDescription(K2_JVERSION == '15' ? $metaDescItem : html_entity_decode($metaDescItem));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$description = preg_replace( '@\{.+?\}@', '', $description);` - you need to use the `\` before `{` and `}` because these are special characters in regex, so you need to escape them with backslash.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but only strips out the curly brackets. We want to strip out the inner of the curly brackets too. Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: Ah, I didn't get it, I will change my answer.